# Javascript Multiple OR Using for-loop in if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/50g49hj3/7/
Select from first selectbox 112,115 and keep from other selectbox if have 112 or 115 and remove if have not

```
if( $(this).val().indexOf(split[0]) != -1 ||
    $(this).val().indexOf(split[1]) != -1 ){

}
```

How can i use this dynamically I want to use my split[] array with foreach and create multiple OR in if condition

If you look my code, you will understand what i want to do.

```
    $('.dd option').each(function() {

if(for(i=0; i<split.length; i++){
  $(this).val().indexOf(split[0]) != -1 || } ){

    }else {

        $(this).remove();
    }

});
```

I want to look my all split array elements like 110, 112, 115 and I want to search it in $(this).val() like

if($string==110 or $string==112 or $string==112) {
  If string has any number, I will keep them
} 
else {
  I will remove them
}

Im still searching answer..

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly - not sure what this is asking.

Comment: Are you using PHP for server script?

Comment: if(for(i=0; i<split.length; i++){
$(this).val().indexOf(split[i]) != -1 || 
} ){

}
i want this but javascript giving me a syntax error

Comment: Please write pseudo code, step by step of what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$('.dd option').each(function() {
var remove=true;
for(elem in split)
  if ($(this).val().indexOf(elem)!= -1)
  {
     remove=false;
     break;
  }
if (remove)
  $(this).remove();
```

});

Comment: No ,
I want the use for in if because i need to use OR in all loop

Comment: This behaves as an OR if you `break` the loop as soon as you find an occurrence. It is equivalent to your code but general for the size of `split`

Comment: This will work exactly as you request, please check this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs0tu5p1/) and accept my answer.

Comment: Dude you are doing $(this).val() if havent 112 , you are removing him but if $(this).val() if have 110 i did not remove him and 110 = split[1] 112 = split[0]

Comment: ok, I have edited the solution and the fiddle. See if it works for you and accept the answer if so. http://jsfiddle.net/vs0tu5p1/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/50g49hj3/3/ Okey there is jsfiddle
Just select 112,155 from first selectbox and i want from you to delete if any option have 112 or 115 thanks..

Comment: sorry for wrong comment i want from you to keep if any option have 112 or 115  :) sorry

Comment: Its not working select from first selectbox 112,115 and look thirth selectbox because thirth selecbox have 115 but you are removing it

Comment: That's right. Bad indentation led me to misplace a bracket. Here's the correct one. http://jsfiddle.net/50g49hj3/10/ Regards.

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
for (var i = 0; i<split.length(); i++){
  if( $(this).val().indexOf(split[i]) != -1){

  }
}
```

Not 100% sure about the commands i used, but see this as an idea ;)

Comment: You should break inside the `if` statement since it should be done only once

Comment: Where is the OR ? We cant solve this problem without using OR

Comment: @TalipDurmuş Yes you can, it is an implicit OR than looping and checking `if` each time, just try it

Comment: @TalipDurmuş Yeah but what for, i dont get it oO
What about two loops:
Loop through one array, inside loop through the second and compare then.

Are you trying to find out if the values in one array are in the second?